# sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command

Tags: shell, sed

```bash
sed -i 's/countFresh=`docker exec -it/countFresh=`docker exec/g' install-ONP.sh
```

Using this in pipeline script but getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Is your _actual_ command also using single quotes around the `sed` expression?

Comment: What's a *pipeline script*?

Comment: I believe your backticks (`) need to be escaped.